# Setting jQuery plugin options from data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a problem setting options to an array value in a jQuery plugin using data attributes.

If I reference the data attribute using a class selector

```
  $('.tm-input').tagsManager(
    {
    prefilled: $('.tm-input').data('load')
    })
```

It works but all the elements get the same values.
If I reference using "this" it sets the correct values but it comes across as a string not an array.

```
  $('.tm-input').tagsManager(
    {
    prefilled: $(this).data('load')
    })
```

I've tried using JSON.parse() but I get an error about an unexpected character.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show the strings that appear in the data-attributes. The problem is most likely because there is an illegal character somewhere in your data causing the JSON to be invalid.

Comment: post the html code also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried each

```
$('.tm-input').each (function () {
    $(this).tagsManager( { prefilled: $(this).data('load') });
});
```

Explanation:

When a selector has more than 1 element, applying a method to it will typically affect all of the elements, but retrieving a property will typically only return that property from the 1st element.

So when you use `.tagsManager` on your $('.tm-input') selector, you are applying `.tagsManger` to all of the elements. But when you set `prefilled:$('.tm-input').data('load')`, the data method is only grabbing the data from the first element in the list, every single time.

When you use `each`, it applies the logic inside of the `each` block to each element individually, rather than all of them at once, so when you use `$(this).data('load')`, it grabs the load attribute from each individual element as well.

Comment: BINGO!  I would love to understand why that works, but I will not argue with success! Thanks chiliNUT!

Comment: @SteveO7 I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: So when adding methods that require element specific options like this, looping through with each is more precise.  That makes sense.